# Count number of numeric records between a set interval in SQL

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a column in a table that looks something like this:

```
DATE
20200101
20200101
20200101
20200102
20200103
20200103
```

I want to extract the number of records for intervals of 7. The start / end dates I'm looking at are 20210101 to 20231130. Although the column is called `DATE`, it is a **numeric** column, not a date one. **EDIT**: the source table is numeric, but its type can be changed if needed. The end result should look like:

| WEEK | COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 20200101 | 10 |
| 20200108 | 2 |

How do  I do this?

Comment: I'd say the opposite, ideally it should be a date data type column. (Otherwise periods overlapping month/year changes will be very complex. Feb 29 for instance.)

Comment: Do You provide starting Date? Is it always 20200101 ?

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS you are using

Comment: @jarlh Good point -- I edited the question to reflect this. The data comes to me in numeric though, ideally I don't want to change the source table.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `TO_DATE` to convert the numeric column into date, then use the group your data by month and intervals of 7 days using integer division :

```
SELECT MIN(DT) as WEEK, COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC(MONTH, TO_DATE(DT::STRING, 'YYYYMMDD')),
         (DAY(TO_DATE(DT::STRING, 'YYYYMMDD'))/ 7)::int
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
DATE
20200101
20200101
20200101
20200102
20200103
20200103
20200108
```

Results :

```
WEEK        COUNT(*)
20200101    6
20200108    1
```

Comment: This is great except I have records for 3+ years. I don't think I could SELECT each date manually

Comment: I have just used some data from CTE to explain my query, You won't need to select rows manually, please check my recent edit